# How to ensure that features dont get overidden

Tags: 7, features

I tried many times with many setting in features but when i add it and enable it always its overridden and i have to go and revert it. Basically block settings and strongarm have to reverted. So is there anything that i ensure while creating features such that it does not get overridden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of reasons why Features may automatically show as overridden after being installed and not manually changing any Drupal configurations related to the Feature. There is a documentation page about this issue: [Troubleshooting: Reasons Features May Be Stuck as Overridden](http://drupal.org/node/986932). That documentation page is not complete, but it links to a Features issue queue thread where a lot more of the possible problems are outlined.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a feature, you create it from what's defined in your database. After enabling the feature the Feature module will detect you have a version in code and a version in database and will most often display this as the feature being overwritten. This is simply how the module works, and I don't think it would be possible to change that. Not without a lot of effort and a lot of skill/knowledge.